# DeleteRequest example with elastic 8.3.0 java api client

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I need examples for DeleteRequest with respect to ES 8.3.0 Java Api client.
I am looking for code reference where I want to delete one particular document by passing index name and the condition to delete the document.
I have found only  **Java High Level Rest Client**(Deprecated in 7.15.0), and
**Transport Client**(Deprecated in 7.0.0).

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for delete specific document using `id`:

```java
DeleteRequest request = DeleteRequest.of(d -> d.index("index_name").id("doc_id"));
DeleteResponse response = esClient.delete(request);
```

If you want to do DeleteByQuery then you can use below code (it will delete document where country is india):

```java
DeleteByQueryRequest dbyquery = DeleteByQueryRequest
                .of(fn -> fn.query(TermQuery.of(tq -> tq.field("country").value("india"))._toQuery()).index("index_name"));
        
DeleteByQueryResponse dqr = esClient.deleteByQuery(dbyquery);
```

There is no details document available for above. You can see open github issue for same [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/issues/281)